# How to revert the style of checkbox ticks from iTextSharp to iText7

Tags: c#, .net, itext, .net-6.0, itext7

I'm trying to migrate the usage of iTextSharp in our .NET 6 project to use iText7 and while I have most issues solved one thing I can't find anything about is how the default tick style changed from the left image to the right.

iTextSharp tick:

[image: iTextSharp tick]

iText 7 tick:

[image: iText7 tick]

Using `.SetCheckType(CheckBoxType.CROSS)` doesn't produce the effect we'd like:

[image]

In our old code this is all we did for the checkboxes.

```cs
case FormFieldType.CHECKBOX:
    if (string.Equals(formField.Value, "true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        acroFields.SetField(ControlName, "X");
    break;
```

With the new code I've attempted multiple things. Tried the `GetField(X).SetValue(X)` close approximation methods to iTextSharp, I've tried modifying the field's font to use ZapfDingbats for a closer cross, and tried replacing the field entirely with a custom paragraph to feign the effect I wanted. That last method worked for the most part, but for some forms we have, it didn't work at all. Here's the code of what I've tried.

Replacing Font:

```cs
case FormFieldType.CHECKBOX:

    if (string.Equals(formField.Value, "true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        acroForm.GetField(controlName).SetFont(zapfdingbats);
        acroForm.GetField(controlName).SetValue("8", true);
    }

    break;
```

Feign Checkbox:

```cs
case FormFieldType.CHECKBOX:

    if (string.Equals(formField.Value, "true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        acroForm.GetField(controlName).SetValue("");

        var boundsPos = acroForm.GetField(controlName).GetWidgets()[0].GetRectangle();

        var calculatedLLX = boundsPos.GetAsNumber(0).FloatValue();
        var calculatedLLY = boundsPos.GetAsNumber(1).FloatValue();
        var calculatedURX = boundsPos.GetAsNumber(2).FloatValue();
        var calculatedURY = boundsPos.GetAsNumber(3).FloatValue();

        if (Math.Abs(calculatedLLX - formField.LLX) >= 1)
        {
            calculatedLLX = formField.LLX;
        }

        if (Math.Abs(calculatedLLY - formField.LLY) >= 1)
        {
            calculatedLLY = formField.LLY;
        }

        if (Math.Abs(calculatedURX - formField.URX) >= 1)
        {
            calculatedURX = formField.URX;
        }

        if (Math.Abs(calculatedURY - formField.URY) >= 1)
        {
            calculatedURY = formField.URY;
        }

        float baseWidth = calculatedURX - calculatedLLX;
        float baseHeight = calculatedURY - calculatedLLY;

        float centerX = (calculatedLLX + calculatedURX) / 2;
        float centerY = (calculatedLLY + calculatedURY) / 2;

        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("8")
                      .SetFont(zapfdingbats)
                      .SetFontSize(baseHeight)
                      .SetFixedPosition(formPage.PageNumber, centerX - baseWidth / 3, centerY - baseHeight / 1.75f, baseWidth)
                      .SetPadding(0)
                      .SetMargin(0)
                      .SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
                      .SetVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
        doc.Add(p);
    }

    acroFields.Remove(controlName);

    break;
```